# Which operations are required to accept an offer?

Tags: operations, offer, trade

If an account has posted an offer, what is/are the operation(s) required to accept that offer?

Is it a combination of `Payment` and `Manage Offer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Stellar developers' guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/trade.html), a trade is effected when a second offer matching the first is posted.